# httpd.conf not doing anything

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, httpd.conf

I had the problem that my `.htaccess` file was not doing anything at all. I tried to put some garbage in but no affect - I did not get any error and site was still working. I was looking for solutions so I found there can be an issue in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. I set

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

instead of overrinding `none`. I restarted server and the site was still working without any error. Then I tried to remove everything from the `http.conf` and restart the site was still running. Why is there no affect?

I am using `php71`. Sites are running via `Laravel valet`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, it was pretty obvious, the laravel valet is using `ngnix` so it makes sense the `httpd.conf` doesn't affect my sites. So I also cannot use `.htaccess` doing that